# Java Won't install on Windows 8.1 - Error 1619

Tags: java, windows

I've offline installer and i'm trying to install `jre-8u25 x64` . I had successfully installed it before and was able to run Eclipse too but, after i uninstalled java and i'm getting following error everytime.

[image]

Please help me out, i posted my problem on oracle forums, but all is a waste. Thank You!!

Comment: Did you uninstall and try again?

Comment: yes, even i refreshed my pc to default, still same error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the last answer of this link can help you:

> http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/windows-installer-error-1619-this-installation-package-could-not-xp-sp2.30039/

Hope it works for you ;) (Even if its about XP the Problem should be the same)